# Why does increasing the encryption policy to FUTURE break some websites?

Tags: encryption, ssl, gnutls

I edited [`/etc/crypto-policies/config`](https://man.linuxreviews.org/man7/crypto-policies.7.html) to change the system-wide crypto policy from DEFAULT to FUTURE, ran `update-crypto-policies`, and afterwards the RSS/ATOM feed aggregator `akregator` wasn't loading pages.  However, if I change the policy to NEXT I have no problems.  Does the FUTURE policy force the use of [TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) 1.3, which I know some of the sites in question don't support via `wget --secure-protocol=TLSv1_3 [URL]`?

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer by running plain [`wget`](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) on a site in question, since `wget` uses [gnutls](https://gnutls.org/).  I got this error:

```
ERROR: The certificate of ‘xkcd.com’ is not trusted.
ERROR: The certificate of ‘xkcd.com’ was signed using an insecure algorithm.
```

Looking at the site's certificate with my browser I see that it uses two fingerprinting algorithms, [SHA-256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) and [SHA-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1). Looking in the `gnutls.txt` config file in `/usr/share/crypto-policies/FUTURE` one can see that both of those algorithms are marked insecure:

```
$ egrep 'SHA1|SHA256' gnutls.txt

tls-disabled-mac = SHA1
insecure-sig = RSA-SHA1
insecure-sig = DSA-SHA1
insecure-sig = ECDSA-SHA1
insecure-sig = DSA-SHA256
```

And one can also see that distrust of SHA1 was added between NEXT and FUTURE:

```
$ diff -u NEXT/gnutls.txt FUTURE/gnutls.txt  | grep SHA1

+tls-disabled-mac = SHA1
+insecure-sig = RSA-SHA1
 insecure-sig = DSA-SHA1
+insecure-sig = ECDSA-SHA1
```

Also, [it would seem that the FUTURE policy is meant for testing by developers rather than use by end users](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1803352#c3):

> Yes, this is expected behaviour. The FUTURE policy requires 3072 bit RSA certificates or ECDSA certificates which are not common yet.
>
> We are not going to change the FUTURE policy. Its purpose is for testing for full 128 bit security readiness (2k RSA certs are too small for that) and not general purpose usability.